# move_uploaded_file not working in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: php

hey guys, am having a bit of a problem here, move_uploaded_file is not actually working at all, and its showing some warnings in my terminal.

my code:

```
$name =  $_FILES['file']['name'];
$size =  $_FILES['file']['size'];
$type =  $_FILES['file']['type'];
$error =  $_FILES['file']['error'];
$temp =  $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$destination = "uploads/";

if($size > 10000000) {
    exit("file size is too big, Max allowed size is 10Mbs");
}

if($type == "application/x-ms-dos-executable") {
    exit("not allowed file formatt.");
}

move_uploaded_file($temp, $destination.$name);
```

terminal:

```
[Sat May 14 15:14:01 2011] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(uploads/gears_16.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/alex/fileupload/upload.php on line 18, referer: http://localhost/alex/fileupload/
[Sat May 14 15:14:01 2011] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpMxKzds' to 'uploads/gears_16.png' in /var/www/alex/fileupload/upload.php on line 18, referer: http://localhost/alex/fileupload/
```

and files wont move, the source, destination and file permissions are 777.
this is getting frustrating :(

Comment: It seems your script haven't permission to move the file.

Comment: visit this page http://www.htmlite.com/php042.php

Comment: On a separate note, it's better to maintain a file type whitelist as opposed to a blacklist, in most cases.

Comment: The folder you want to upload to is
/var/www/alex/fileupload/uploads
or
/var/www/alex/uploads

And the permission is 777 right?

Comment: @nick very interesting, ill add it up :)

Comment: @0xali i want to upload a file to /var/www/alex/fileupload/uploads and its permissions is 777 alright

Comment: @lightWing am using ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo chown alex -R /var/www`

`sudo chgrp www-data -R /var/www`

`sudo chmod 0751 -R /var/www`

//mentioned here
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=560592

Comment: still giving me this 
[Sat May 14 18:18:50 2011] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(/var/www/alex/fileupload/uploads/to be fixed): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/alex/fileupload/upload.php on line 18, referer: http://localhost/alex/fileupload/
[Sat May 14 18:18:50 2011] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpo09fxg' to '/var/www/alex/fileupload/uploads/to be fixed' in /var/www/alex/fileupload/upload.php on line 18, referer: http://localhost/alex/fileupload/

Comment: Do you have any Apache/PHP security mods? or any hardened security?

Comment: please elaborate what do u mean by secuirty mods, and about hardened security, no i dont use anything, i use ubuntu out of the box.

Comment: I meant something like SuPHP or suhosin.

Answer (score 0):

- In **Ubuntu**, you have to give the **destination directory** permission to daemon user.
- In my case, i have my workspace in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/students/** and have a folder like this **/opt/lampp/htdocs/students/uploadedFilesDestination**.
- I want to put my uploaded files into **uploadedFilesDestination** folder.
  The thing here is that ubuntu's kernel/threads have to have the permission to the target directory.
- You might have to use the following piece of command to do so. 
  open terminal and follow the command

> **sudo chown daemon /opt/lampp/htdocs/student/uploadedFilesDestination**

**daemon** is important. daemon is the *user for kernel permissions.